# Trigger click event on class in tokenformatter of added jquery tokeninput

Tags: jquery, jquery-tokeninput

I am using jquery token input with below initialization:

```
      $("#abc").tokenInput(jsonData,
      {
        propertyToSearch: "name",
        tokenFormatter: function(item){
          return "<li><p>abcdefg</p><a href='#' class='test-link'>TEST</li>";
        }
      }
```

Now When I click on "TEST" I want to execute some functionality. I have written click event on the jquery class attribute "test-link", click event is not firing.

How to trigger click event on the "TEST".

Comment: Have you found any answer for this yet? I am trying to get 2nd textbox input when start typing in the tokenInput field, but it seems tokenInput doesn't like  to be within any event handler.

Answer (score 0):

What about pure JS ?

```
<a href='#' class='test-link' onclick='yourFunction()'>TEST</a>
```

Edit: And your  tag is not closed, maybe that's the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Use [on](https://api.jquery.com/on/).

```
  $(document).on("click" , ".test-link" , function() {
     alert('Clicked');
  });
```

Comment: I know this will work but wanted to do in tokeninput initialization itself. That is the main purpose of this question.